# Python slice assignment changes nearby element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I define `n x n` array of bools like this:

```
grid = [[False for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
```

This function sets rectangular region of that grid to state (True or False)

```
def set_region(grid, points, state):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = points
    row = [state] * (x2 - x1 + 1)
    for y in range (y1, y2 + 1):
        grid[y][x1:x2] = row
```

Region is defined by 2 corner points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`
`y` corresponds to row, `x` is a column

When I'm using this function to set whole region to `True`, it works fine, but when I'm trying to change it to `False`, it changes, but next element in row after changed element becomes `True`

Example:

```
n = 100;
grid = [[False for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)] 
points = 57, 4, 58, 5
set_region(grid, points, True) 
assert (grid[4][57] and grid[4][58] and grid[5][57] and grid[5][58]) == True
assert (grid[4][59] or grid[5][59]) == False
set_region(grid, points, False)
assert (grid[4][57] and grid[4][58] and grid[5][57] and grid[5][58]) == False
assert (grid[4][59] or grid[5][59]) == False
```

The last assertion hereby fails. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me. End index of slice in Python is exclusive. This works fine

```
grid[y][x1:x2+1] = row
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem are yours +1 in set_range, they end up agregating more stuff to the grip, remove all, unless that is the desire behavior...

Comment: I added +1 to range() argument since it's exclusive, and I need inclusive values